# Regular expression: multiple occurences of a word, replace only last occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have an URL like this:

```
http://site.com/galleries/galleryname/imageID123/lightbox/
```

and using a script to replace the lightbox URL with nothing (when lightbox overlay is closed):

```
document.URL.replace('lightbox/', '')
```

Things get messy when user has a gallery also named "lightbox", then  the URL is:

```
http://site.com/galleries/lightbox/imageID123/lightbox/
```

I need to make sure that docment.URL.replace will replace only the last occurrence of the word.

Comment: What about `http://site.com/galleries/galleryname/imageID123/lightbox/test/` - should this also match?

Comment: Such URL pattern will never exist (code status 404), so I'm not worried about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
document.URL.replace(/lightbox\/$/, '')
```

*Im talking as the parser :*

```
document.URL.replace('lightbox/', '')
```

Ok , whenever i find `lightbox/` i will replace it with `"empty"`
but wait ! there's more than 1 . so I'll do it .

but wait ! since you **didnt** supply the `g` flag - i will do it only to the first.
(if you did supply the g flag it will replace ALL occurrences !)

any way -

we dont want that.

so how do we tell him only the last ?

well use the `$` sign. which represent the end of the string.

so i want you to replace only lightbox which has `/` after and the `/` is the END OF THE WORD.

Comment: He's looking for "lightbox/" at the end of the line.  The "$" tells it to look for the end of the line.  And since "/" is a special character, it gets escaped like so: "\/".